# settings import error in django using virtualenv

Tags: django, virtualenv

I am using ubuntu 12.04.I am using virtualenv and on that I installed all the packages those I required.When I run the project it gives me error but when I run another project it works.
I am using python2.6.8 and django 1.3.1

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "manage.py", line 4, in 
>    import settings # Assumed to be in the same directory.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your directory structure in question.

Comment: /home/milind/virt_env/sis/sisport_prod/src/settings.py

here sis is my virtual env.And in that I placed project sisport_prod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Import `settings.py` in python shell, there it will give you the exact error. I think you import some other modules in settings.py those giving you `ImportError`.

Comment: Thanx man.....Error in my settings.py.I have to resolve first.then It may not give error for import settings.